# How to display router view with VUEJS3 in a build project for google chrome extension

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vue-router, vuejs3, browser-extension

I am trying to create a chromium extension with VueJS3.
Locally, everything works, the components are displayed where they need to be.
But once exporting in Chrome extensions, nothing is displayed except the first component of my App.js. Why?

❤︎ manifest.json:

```
{
   "name" : "MyProject",
   "version" : "0.20.1",
   "permissions": ["cookies", "webRequest", "tabs", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
   "background": {
       "scripts": [
         "/js/browser-polyfill.js",
         "/js/browser-polyfill.js.map",
         "/js/chunk-vendors.6711c78c.js",
         "/js/chunk-vendors.6711c78c.js.map",
         "/js/app.b9302fd1.js",
         "/js/app.b9302fd1.js.map"
       ],
       "persistent": true
   },
   "content_scripts": [{
       "matches": [
           "<all_urls>" 
       ],
       "js": [
           "/js/browser-polyfill.js",
           "/js/browser-polyfill.js.map",
           "/js/chunk-vendors.6711c78c.js",
           "/js/chunk-vendors.6711c78c.js.map",
           "/js/app.b9302fd1.js",
           "/js/app.b9302fd1.js.map"
       ]
   }],
   "browser_action": {
       "default_title": "MyProject",
       "default_popup": "index.html"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

❤︎ router.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
//first level
import Overview from "../views/Overview.vue";
import Details from "../views/Details.vue";
//second level
import DetailsInfo from "@/components/Details-Info.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Overview",
    component: Overview
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

❤︎ app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GeneralNavigation />
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>

</template>
```

And for a visual explication: [The local result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYukz.png) and [The extension result (after build)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFpQZ.png)

Comment: I assume you need to dynamically import the created files into your `manifest.json`. You see, after each build the files will create a new hash -> `app.b9302fd1.js` can become `app.bd52a9d2.js`. Or is the `manifest.json` a result after you have build your project? Sorry I have never worked with Chrome extensions yet.

Comment: i import each file manually into my json file, i dont know how to do it dynamically? The manifest.json is not created directly by VUE CLI; I add it to be able to use my application as an extension. There may be a way to automate that indeed ??

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer!
Google chrome exetension use a relative path which matches with the file structure of the folder.

I simply change my main route "/" as "/index.html" in Router.js before building the application and this is worked!

❤︎ router.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
//first level
import Overview from "../views/Overview.vue";
import Details from "../views/Details.vue";
//second level
import DetailsInfo from "@/components/Details-Info.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/index.html",
    name: "Overview",
    component: Overview
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

I hope it's can be usefull for other!