# How to use VueRouter in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've been making a chrome extension with Vue 3 + VueRouter.

With the router.push functionality I was trying to change router-view content to a different component, meaning showing a different UI to users.

However, no matter what methods I use, I just can't change the view.

So my App.vue has router-view and I have two components that I would like to show one at a time.

Component One is About and Component Two is Home.

What I did was that I created a method that fires off on onClick event.

So, the first view is Home (users see this view first). Then when a user clicks a button, it will swap the UI component, showing About Page. I used router.push('/about') to swap the UI component to About.vue. It was unsuccessful.

I am aware of the fact that the chrome extensions are not really a web page so the routing is different but nothing seems to work.

I've checked this reference and tried it and sadly it was futile

[How to display router view with VUEJS3 in a build project for google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747257/how-to-display-router-view-with-vuejs3-in-a-build-project-for-google-chrome-exte)

router.js

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/index.html",
    component: () => import("../src/App.vue"),
    name: "App",
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    component: () => import("../src/views/About.vue"),
    name: "About",
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory("index.html"),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./index.css";
import store from "./store/index";
import router from "./router";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(store);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

App.vue (when I was using router-view)

```js
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

If I do router-view like that on Chrome extension, nothing is showing

So I did this also to change the view by using router-link. It didn't work as well. By clicking router-link tag, nothing was working.

```js
<template>
 <Login />
<router-link to="/about"> About </router-link>
</template>
```

```js
methods: {
  routerPush() {
      this.$router.push("about");
      this.$router.push("/about"); tried both / and without /
    },
}

<template>
 <Login />
<span @click="routerPush"> About </span> 
</template>
```

Did the above code to just to try out the router.push functionality. It was unsuccessful

Comment: Try using hash mode in the router.

Comment: Check the comment in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524694/12962668).

Comment: @wOxxOm I did use history: createWebHashHistory() and nothing seems to be working..

Comment: @Zarko I've checked that already and followed it, however not working solution for me :(

Comment: @espc Stange. Ok, a couple of things. Can you share how you actually use `router.push`, also, where you are using `router-view` ?   Can you give us at least a portion of `App.vue`? I assume that is your start point. Besides that, try ``router-link  to see if this actually works.

Comment: @Zarko Hi, thanks for following up, I've updated with App.vue and don't mind the minor syntax differences I just quickly updated to show you what I did in terms of methods I've used

Comment: Have you tried with `mode: "abstract"` ? Perhaps these can help - https://dev.to/rezvitsky/chrome-extension-vue-3-vue-router-typescript-vite-tailwindcss-42d0 and https://www.streaver.com/blog/posts/create-web-extension-vue

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thank you for references, I've already checked out the first one. I even git cloned it to see it for myself but the project is not working. The first one is the one I needed different components and VueRouter setup but mine looks identical to the first one and not working :(

Comment: According to the thread mentioned by Zarko, they suggest using `history` mode rathre than `hash` mode, to push to your home route when the App is created and to match/follow the folders hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The reason Vue router wasn't working is because I didn't have a renderer Vue to mount

You will need to have a component Renderer.vue or whatever that would contain  in template and mount that component in main.js createApp(Renderer) like this